# Compare the result of Gaussian elimination with the output of numpy.linalg.solve

Tags: python, numpy, numerical-methods

In the following code I have implemented Gaussian elimination with partial pivoting for a general square linear system Ax=b. I have tested my code and it produced the right output. I have used it to solve Ax=b where A is a random 100x100 matrix and b is a random 100x1 vector.**

However now I am looking for some help with comparing my solution against the solution obtained by using `numpy.linalg.solve`. How to add this comparison to my code?

```
import numpy as np
def GEPP(A, b, doPricing = True):
    '''
    Gaussian elimination with partial pivoting.
    input: A is an n x n numpy matrix
           b is an n x 1 numpy array
    output: x is the solution of Ax=b 
        with the entries permuted in 
        accordance with the pivoting 
        done by the algorithm
    post-condition: A and b have been modified.
    '''
    n = len(A)
    if b.size != n:

        raise ValueError("Invalid argument: incompatible sizes between"+

                     "A & b.", b.size, n)

    # k represents the current pivot row. Since GE traverses the matrix in the 

    # upper right triangle, we also use k for indicating the k-th diagonal 

    # column index.

    # Elimination

    for k in range(n-1):

        if doPricing:

            # Pivot

            maxindex = abs(A[k:,k]).argmax() + k

            if A[maxindex, k] == 0:


                raise ValueError("Matrix is singular.")

            # Swap

            if maxindex != k:

                A[[k,maxindex]] = A[[maxindex, k]]

                b[[k,maxindex]] = b[[maxindex, k]]

        else:

            if A[k, k] == 0:

                raise ValueError("Pivot element is zero. Try setting doPricing to True.")

       #Eliminate

       for row in range(k+1, n):

           multiplier = A[row,k]/A[k,k]

           A[row, k:] = A[row, k:] - multiplier*A[k, k:]

           b[row] = b[row] - multiplier*b[k]

    # Back Substitution

    x = np.zeros(n)

    for k in range(n-1, -1, -1):

        x[k] = (b[k] - np.dot(A[k,k+1:],x[k+1:]))/A[k,k]

    return x



if __name__ == "__main__":
    A = np.round(np.random.rand(100, 100)*10)
    b =  np.round(np.random.rand(100)*10)
    print (GEPP(np.copy(A), np.copy(b), doPricing = False))
```

Comment: You've described a situation and posted code (correctly formatted! good job! formatting is confusing on this site), but it's not clear what question you're trying to ask us. We need a specific question to go on, not just "looking for some help". We can't tell what help you need.

Comment: i am trying to compare my solution against the solution obtained using numpy.linalg.solve but i am not sure how to implement that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compare the two solutions, use [`np.allclose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html) which verifies that two arrays agree, element by element, within some reasonably margins. One should not expect exact equality in floating point arithmetics.

```
my_solution = GEPP(np.copy(A), np.copy(b), doPricing=False)
numpy_solution = np.linalg.solve(A, b)
if np.allclose(my_solution, numpy_solution):
    print("Yay")
else:
    print("NOOOOO")
```

This prints "Yay".

Comment: thanks for your post, how could i print out the solutions given by np.linalg.solve(A,b)?

Comment: would print (numpy_solution) do it?